# Angular gives blank page when i use ui.bootstrap in my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use the the angular bootstrap when i try to add the dependency in my controller and start the server with grunt serve i get a blank page.Please have a look at the bower components in the screen shot.

When i try to use it in `angular.module('kbv1App', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller` it fails if i remove the `[ui.bootstrap]` it works fine.

Any idea wha will be the issue?

[image]

Update. Console error

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.bootstrap minErr/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:5 setupModuleLoader/</module/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1645:1 ensure@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1567:5 module@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1641:7 createInjector/loadModules/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3817:11 forEach@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:320:7 loadModules@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3811:5 createInjector/loadModules/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3818:11 forEach@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:320:7 loadModules@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3811:5 createInjector@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3751:3 bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1410:1 bootstrap@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1425:5 angularInit@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1338:5 @http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:21713:5 jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3119:1 jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3231:7 .ready@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3443:3 completed@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3474:3
```

Comment: Whenever you have such errors, do yourself a favor and look at the browser developer console log (F12), most probably there you would see some errors that can help you and add that to the question too.

Comment: @Chandermani i agree there was a error but i was not able to find anything in that.

Comment: I have updated the question with the error @Chandermani

Comment: Verify the ui-bootstrap-tpls.js file is getting sent to the browser, you should NOT be loading the bootstrap.js library.

Comment: Could you provide the _bower commands_ you used to install the dependencies? I cannot reproduce your issue at the moment, but many people have had problems setting up the ui-bootstrap through bower.

Answer (score 2):

The reason people are using `angular-ui-bootstrap` is to **avoid** using `jquery` and `bootstrap.js` (which relies on jquery) and opt for an Angular solution. So my first attempt at getting this app working is to

- **Remove** `jquery.js`, `jquery-ui.js`, and `bootstrap.js` out of the page.
- Start from just plain Angular + Angular UI Bootstrap first. Try some examples from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ if you want to get familiar with the directive usage.
- Then, if you really need to, just add `jquery` back in later. But from my experience, you won't really need to if you stick to Angular way of coding. If you come from a strong `jquery` background and just start coding on Angular, I recommend you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/3788115

Answer (score 0):

<del>The component `angular-bootstrap` should have two javascript files:

    bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js
    bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

You only include the templates.</del>

Edit: Corrected in the comments.

Use [Chrome Canary](http://www.google.com/intl/hu/chrome/browser/canary.html) for easier debugging, you will see the full error message instead of `Uncaught object`.

Comment: Sorry no luck still i have same issue.

Comment: Can you update the question with the full error message, please? (Use Firefox or Chrome Canary.)

Comment: You do not want to load both of those files, use one or the other. One version contains the html templates (tpls) and one does not, both contain the directives.

Comment: But still i am getting the issue" [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. "But i have the module in the bower_component folder.

Answer (score 0):

add `['ui.bootstrap']` on the main app.js