# using ui.bootstrap in angular js application

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

i am working on an angular application, that requires a table to be paginated. I have tried using [dir-pagination by Michael Bromley](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) but that didn't work out well when i tried to use `angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);`
I then tried using ui.bootstrap but that did'nt work out either. In fact even leaving an empty square brackets is causing a blank page. Without the square brackets the app is working fine.

I have gone through SO and found a similar problem ([Angular gives blank page when i use ui.bootstrap in my controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477241/angular-gives-blank-page-when-i-use-ui-bootstrap-in-my-controller)) but i didn't find anything to solve my issue.

I haven't yet coded for pagination, but that should be easy enough! My real problem is that i am not able to understand why I am getting a blank page.

However i tried using dir-pagination and ui.bootstrap on an app with a single page and controller and its working fine. But i need to use these directives on a complex app with multiple pages and controllers.

This is the code that is causing so much trouble.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtrl',function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{ "id": 1, "first_name": "Heather", "last_name": "Bell", "hobby": "Eating" },
                    { "id": 2, "first_name": "Andrea", "last_name": "Dean", "hobby": "Gaming" },
                    { "id": 3, "first_name": "Peter", "last_name": "Barnes", "hobby": "Reading Books" },
                    { "id": 4, "first_name": "Harry", "last_name": "Bell", "hobby": "Youtubing" },
                    { "id": 5, "first_name": "Deborah", "last_name": "Burns", "hobby": "Fishing" },
                    { "id": 6, "first_name": "Larry", "last_name": "Kim", "hobby": "Skipping" },
                    { "id": 7, "first_name": "Jason", "last_name": "Wallace", "hobby": "Football" },
                    { "id": 8, "first_name": "Carol", "last_name": "Williams", "hobby": "Baseball" },
                    { "id": 9, "first_name": "Samuel", "last_name": "Olson", "hobby": "Programming" },
                    { "id": 10, "first_name": "Donna", "last_name": "Evans", "hobby": "Playing DOTA" },
                    { "id": 11, "first_name": "Lois", "last_name": "Butler", "hobby": "Gaming" },
                    { "id": 12, "first_name": "Daniel", "last_name": "Hill", "hobby": "surfing" },
                    { "id": 13, "first_name": "Matthew", "last_name": "Torres", "hobby": "cycling" },
                    { "id": 14, "first_name": "Jerry", "last_name": "Hernandez", "hobby": "Music" },
                    { "id": 15, "first_name": "Christopher", "last_name": "Carpenter", "hobby": "Football" },
                    { "id": 16, "first_name": "Harold", "last_name": "West", "hobby": "Gaming" },
                    { "id": 17, "first_name": "Carol", "last_name": "Hicks", "hobby": "Youtubing" },
                    { "id": 18, "first_name": "Bonnie", "last_name": "Davis", "hobby": "Partying" },
                    { "id": 19, "first_name": "Nancy", "last_name": "Banks", "hobby": "Photography" },
                    { "id": 20, "first_name": "Walter", "last_name": "Freeman", "hobby": "Tweeting" },
                    { "id": 21, "first_name": "Louis", "last_name": "Gonzales", "hobby": "Bloging" },
                    { "id": 22, "first_name": "Jean", "last_name": "Watkins", "hobby": "Bloging" },
                    { "id": 23, "first_name": "Albert", "last_name": "Harris", "hobby": "Music" },
                    { "id": 24, "first_name": "Billy", "last_name": "Owens", "hobby": "Camping" },
                    { "id": 25, "first_name": "Russell", "last_name": "Patterson", "hobby": "Singing" }];

    $scope.sort = function (keyname) {
        $scope.sortKey = keyname;   //set the sortKey to the param passed
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa
    }
});
```

I am a beginner in AngularJS and have no idea as to how to solve the issue. I have gone through a few plunkers but all of them implement a single page app.

Thanks beforehand for the responses!

**Answered my own question

Comment: Can you post the error message that appeared in your console when the page was blank?

Comment: there was no error message in the console! except for a css warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this after 4 years and AngularJS is a dinosaur now, but maybe it might help someone.

I had declared another app module for the 'myApp' in a different file, which is why the error was being displayed.